# TYPO3 modify backend table

Tags: typo3, backend

**EDIT:** TYPO3 version 4.7

there is table Create Website user with many tabs.

I am able to add new tab with my own data using:

```
$test = array(
    'tx_promconf_send_email' => array(
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'HAHAHA',
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'input'
            ,)));

t3lib_div::loadTCA('fe_users');
t3lib_extMgm::addTCAcolumns('fe_users',$test,1);
t3lib_extMgm::addToAllTCAtypes('fe_users','--div--;Documents;;;;1-1-1,tx_promconf_send_email');
```

But I am not able to put my input to already existing tabs. Also I was not able to find some explanation of this string **'fe_users','--div--;Documents;;;;1-1-1,tx_promconf_send_email'**.

Is there an option how to modify existing tabs? Where can I found the name of the tab? I tried to use instead of --div-- name of the tab and it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This weird string is hardly documented. You can find the TCA Documentation [here](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Index.html).

If you want to insert it to an existing tab, just do it by finding a field within the desired tab where you want to put your new field after or before.

For example:

```
t3lib_extMgm::addToAllTCAtypes('fe_users','tx_promconf_send_email', '', 'after:last_name');
```

Your field will now be displayed after the field "last_name", and so within the tab "Personal Data". You can also use "before:*fieldname*" to insert your field before a field.

Comment: I tried this way and it does not work for me. I am not sure if it is not because of the TYPO3 version.

Comment: This should work in 4.7.

So if you want to analyse this, log in to the backend and go to "Admin Tools" => "Configuration" and Select "TCA". There you can view the fe_users columns section, and find out if your new column shows up.

Also note, that you have to clear the Configuration Cache if you make changes in a ext_tables.php

Comment: I found the TCA->fe_users and there is my tx_promconf_send_email item. But if I check the fe form it is still not visible inside.

Comment: My example was slightly wrong, it has to be t3lib_extMgm::addToAllTCAtypes('fe_users','tx_promconf_send_email', '', 'after:last_name');

Comment: I was able to put it there when I edited TCA->fe_users->types. But then I had to modify the crazy link again...

Comment: Now it works with the last solution. t3lib_extMgm::addToAllTCAtypes('fe_users','tx_promconf_send_email', '', 'after:last_name');

Comment: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ExtendingTca/Examples/Index.html?highlight=addtcacolumns